# Transferring large files from S3 to Google Cloud Storage in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I'm using boto in an App Engine backend instance to get the file and the GAE Storage APIs to store it. I raised the default fetch deadline. 
However for files that go over the 32M limit, there's a problem and ResumableDownloadHandler doesn't help there because the GCS file handle has an incompatible interface.

Can anyone suggest an existing solution that would be resumable and not require a file-system?

Comment: How about using gsutil on EC2 or Compute Engine?

Comment: I wouldn't be asking such questions if it were relevant.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known problem, which we're working on. In the meantime you can use the [Google Python client library](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/) as an alternative to the Files API.